# Weird iOS animation, display with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile

I have been working on some animations for a sliding menu with some help from you lovely guys :)

It works perfectly in browsers, but when using an iPad or iPhone (iphone has its own layout) the following occour...

On the home page, after the slider opens, it takes a few seconds to render the menu once the div is opened (opposed to the web version) and sometimes it does not even appear.

On other pages the menu slides open, but once fully open, the text hides its self, then becomes visible once you close the menu, also happers on the sub menu.

link: http://jsre.kandimedia.com/

Really not sure what I should look for when encountering such a error, any advice is much appreciated!

UPDATE

added jsfiddle, tho not sure it would be help as the problem is on mobile/ipad

http://jsfiddle.net/pxd8z/

**EDIT:** Found out the cause, there is a conflict with background.js

Answer (score 0):

Well kinda solved, there was a conflict with backstrech.js