# jQuery code looks butchered, best way to write?

Tags: jquery

I am having a weird problem with iOS and a sliding menu (which can be found at  [Weird iOS animation, display with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431268/weird-ios-animation-display-with-jquery) )

I believe there is a conflict with my scruffy code, and another plugin (as on another version of the site, the sliding menus work with the plugin, but I cannot use that code).

```
$('#menu-item-134 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $('.open'+$(e.target).parent().attr('id').replace('link', ''));

    $('.subnav').not(elm).filter(':visible').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);

    elm.animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});

$('#menu-item-135 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $('.open'+$(e.target).parent().attr('id').replace('link', ''));

    $('.subnav').not(elm).filter(':visible').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);

    elm.animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});​
```

A shortened version of the script can be found on this JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pxd8z/2/

Basically what would be the best way to write that script?

Comment: You should add your code to the question on SO rather than just linking to it.  Also, using vague terms like "butchered" and "scruffy" doesn't really help us much.

Comment: Oh come on. My code is quite a bit more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select both links at once : http://jsfiddle.net/pxd8z/3/

```
$('#menu-item-134 a, #menu-item-135 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $('.open'+$(e.target).parent().attr('id').replace('link', ''));

    $('.subnav').not(elm).filter(':visible').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);

    elm.animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use code like this

```
$('.menu-item a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $('#open'+e.target.parentNode.id);

    $('.subnav:visible').not(elm).animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);

    elm.animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);
});​
```

with this html:

```
<div class="menu-item" id="menu-item-134">
    <a href="#" >
        link1
    </a>
</div>

<div class="menu-item" id="menu-item-135">
    <a href="#" >
        link2
    </a>
</div>

<div class="subnav" id="openmenu-item-134">
    box1
</div>

<div class="subnav" id="openmenu-item-135">
    box2
</div>
```

​

Jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/pbfy0/3qtYm/

Answer (score 0):

a bit more succinct: http://jsfiddle.net/pxd8z/4/

```
$('#menu-item-134 a, #menu-item-135 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $('.open'+$(e.target).parent().attr('id').replace('link', ''));

    $('.subnav:not(' + elm.selector + '):visible').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);

    elm.animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});
```